# Как вставить русский текст в sql запрос?

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x

Пытаюсь выполнить

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO some_data.stories (text) VALUE ("Привет мир")""")
```

А python 3.6 выдаёт ошибку

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in
>   position 45-50: ordinal not in range(256)

Как её исправить?

Comment: Читайте про преобразование `unicode` строк, там используется метка `u`. Пример: `str = u'русская строка'`